# Cache data after urllib.urlopen

Tags: python, unit-testing, urllib, microdata, urlopen

I was trying to write `unittest` for my script which scrapes data after `urllib.urlopen(url)`

But I want to cache the webpage itself so that the tests do not have to load the webpage every time. Is there a way to cache the data and then scrape data .I am using `microdata` to scrape the data.

Comment: `urllib.urlopen` should cache by default. If it is not, I suspect the HTTP headers of the response are instructing it not to.

Comment: @Ben - I thought so , but the tests are reloading webpages again and again. Is there a way to manually set caching on for `urllib`

Comment: Take a look at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/491261-caching-and-throttling-for-urllib2/

Comment: Thanks for helping @Ben , but I found out using `httplib2` seems better option than using `urllib` , what do you think ?

Comment: `httplib2` looks pretty good, with support for caching -- https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/wiki/Examples